# Need a regular expression (q1 - q170)

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to match q1 to q170 (ex. q1, q2, q3... q170) and not q0 or q180 and so on. Help me please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
^q(?:[1-9][0-9]?|1[0-6][0-9]|170)$
```

[See it](http://www.rubular.com/r/rghgL9gbs5)

Comment: Thanks a lot, @codaddict. It really works. You're the magician! I will appreciate if you explain what ?: means.

Comment: A `(..)` in regex is used for grouping and also capturing. But if you want to just group and not capture you use its slight variation `(?...)`. More on this here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html

Answer (score 4):

```
^q([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-6][0-9]|170)$
```

this will exclude q0 as well

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

```
q(170|[0-1][0-6]\d|\d{2}|[1-9])(?!\d)
```

**Demo :**

http://regexr.com?30mp9